# How do I overload the in operator in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading, language-features

```
def array = [1,2,3,4,5]
println 3 in array
```

prints `true`. What do I need to overload to support `in` for any object?

**Example:**

```
class Whatever {
   def addItem(item) {
      // add the item
   }
}

def w = new Whatever()
w.addItem("one")
w.addItem("two")
println "two" in w
```

I know I could make the collection this class uses public, but I'd like to use `in` instead.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what you'd like to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked on the Groovy mailing list. [Here's](http://www.nabble.com/How-can-one-use-the-membership-operator-with-a-custom-class--td25941269.html) the thread. The answer is `isCase`

```
class A
{
  def isCase(o) {
    return false;
  }
}

a = new A()
println 6 in a // returns false
```

Comment: Sweet. After a quick search, looks like that's documented here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN2535-Control#JN2535-Control-ConditionalStatements

Comment: +1. I wish I could vote Guillaume Laforge for this +1, after all, he was the one to answer it on the mailing list ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could make `Whatever` implement [Collection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) or a Collection subinterface. Groovy has an `iterator()` [implementation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#iterator%28%29) for `Object`, and it looks like for operators that work on aggregate objects, Groovy will attempt to convert the Object to a Collection and then perform the aggregate function.

Alternatively, you *might* be able to have `Whatever` implement [Iterable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). I'm still trying to find a reference for this and write a proof of concept to verify it.

The [Groovy documentation for the Iterator Pattern](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Iterator+Pattern) might indicate that this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is possible, the Membership Operator (in) isn't listed on the [Operator Overloading](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading) page.